# Not sure why "the str "True" declared in your code"

Tags: python

RESOLVED!!

So let me start off with I am new to coding.  I am working on assignment for class in Python the instructions are
"Write some code below that will print True if balance is greater than or equal to price, and False if it is not"

This was the pre-built code that I was given to work from:

```
balance = 20.0
price = 19.0
```

My code added was this:

```
if balance >= price:
        print("True")
else:
        print("False")
```

So I get the intended response of  "True" but then when I submit I get the message

```
"We found the str "True" declared in your code. You shouldn't be creating this value manually."
```

Can anyone point me in a direction that will tell me why I am seeing this.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `print(True)` without the quotes? We don't have access to your autograder, so this is just a guess.

Comment: The error message you get is pretty clear, isn't it? What is that you don't understand?

Comment: Shortcut to learn in this context: `print(balance >= price)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
balance = 20.0
price = 19.0

print(balance >= price)
```

I don't exactly know what is going on since this doesn't seem to be a python error but rather an autograder, so if the autograder doesn't want you to define the term manually(i.e. in a string), then maybe it wants you to output the python keyword `True`, hence, this code should work.

NOTE: The output in the terminal/console will be the same, this implementation is just a guess of how the autograder may want the code to be written.